# render pdf using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf-generation, data-uri

In my App I need render a dynamic pdf.
I have an ajax function that call a php function that return a pdf (string format).

Now I render this pdf using data-uri in this way:

```
window.open('data:application/pdf;base64, ' + response);
```

...but this works only on chrome.
How can I get that also on firefox?

Comment: Tried this http://andreasgal.com/2011/06/15/pdf-js/ ? Also, refer http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/784207

Answer (score 0):

Hmm how about having your PHP create a temporary local file on the server, and opening that one in your window.open()?

Base64 if very verbose and I am sure you'd get better performance out of just loading it directly from the server (where it actually gets created). Same number of requests, better performance, what could you ask more? ;-)

Comment: I don't create physical file, for this reason I need render the pdf with javascript.

Comment: is the file created on the server side? You could still directly stream to the output without actually saving it anywhere - [last example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp). Hope this helps